# sum criteria select/condition in yii

Tags: yii

It doesn't say what error it is but it doesn't display properly. I think it's trying to display an array but I thought the criteria is summing the stars, no?

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $prod_id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id');
    $count = Review::model()->countByAttributes(array('target_product_id'=>$prod_id));
    $criteria->select = 'sum(star) AS sum';
    $criteria->condition = 'target_product_id = $prod_id';
    $total = $model->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [queryScalar()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryScalar-detail) to solve this very simply.

```
        echo Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT SUM(star) FROM YourStarTable where target_product_id=$prod_id")->queryScalar();
```

OR

```
        $id=2;
        $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
        $command->select('SUM(star) AS sum');
        $command->from('YourStarTable');
        $command->where('target_product_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));
        echo $command->queryScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might lie on this line

```
$criteria->condition = 'target_product_id = $prod_id';
```

It should read

```
$criteria->condition = 'target_product_id = ' . $prod_id;
```

Comment: i see the problem, it returns $criteria->select = 'sum(star) AS sum' as a string... but star is an int.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
 `$criteria->condition = "target_product_id = $prod_id";`
**Either change the single quotes to double quotes** 

 **OR**

```
$criteria->condition = 'target_product_id = :name';
$criteria->params=array(':name'=>$prod_id);
```